# A very simple stoper

Tags: java, android

So 2 days ago I've started learning Android technology. I've written very simple program which can count a time using  CountDownTimer class. Here is my xml code:

```
<RelativeLayout

xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#000000"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:id="@+id/raf">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnStart"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="28dp"
    android:textColor="#76EE00"
    android:background="#2C3529"
    android:text="Start" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnStop"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="28dp"
    android:textColor="#76EE00"
    android:background="#2C3529"
    android:text="Stop" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewHours"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btnStart"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:textColor="#76EE00"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:text="Godziny:"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewMinutes"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textViewHours"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:textColor="#76EE00"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:text="Minuty:"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewSeconds"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textViewMinutes"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:textColor="#76EE00"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:text="Sekundy:"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewTime"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/btnStop"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="17dp"
    android:textColor="#76EE00"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editHours"
    android:numeric="integer"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btnStop"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="220dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
    android:text="1"
    android:background="#2C3529"
    android:textColor="#76EE00"
    />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editMinutes"
    android:numeric="integer"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editHours"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="220dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:text="0"
    android:background="#2C3529"
    android:textColor="#76EE00"
    />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editSeconds"
    android:numeric="integer"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editMinutes"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="220dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:text="0"
    android:background="#2C3529"
    android:textColor="#76EE00"
    />
```

And here we have java code:

```
   package com.example.rafa.minutnik;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
@SuppressLint("NewApi")

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private Button btnStart,btnStop;
    private TextView textViewTime;
    private EditText editHours, editMinutes, editSeconds;
    private int Time;

    public void reset(){
        editHours.setText("");
        editMinutes.setText("");
        editSeconds.setText("");
        textViewTime.setText("");
    }

    @Override
    public View findViewById(int id) {
        return super.findViewById(id);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btnStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStart);
        btnStop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStop);
        textViewTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewTime);
        editHours = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editHours);
        editMinutes = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editMinutes);
        editSeconds = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editSeconds);

        Time = 3600*Integer.parseInt(editHours.getText().toString()) +
                60*Integer.parseInt(editMinutes.getText().toString()) +
                Integer.parseInt(editSeconds.getText().toString());

        final CounterClass timer = new CounterClass(1000*Time,1000);

        btnStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                timer.start();
            }
        });

        btnStop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                timer.cancel();
                reset();
            }
        });
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public class CounterClass extends CountDownTimer{

        public CounterClass(long milisInFuture, long countDownInterval){

            super(milisInFuture,countDownInterval);
        }

        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

            long milis = millisUntilFinished;
            String hms = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(milis),
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(milis) - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(milis)),
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(milis) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(milis)));

            System.out.println(hms);
            textViewTime.setText(hms);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {

            textViewTime.setText("Finished.");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

But there is one big drawback, it can count only time from beginning value which is fixed. As you can see I put new edittext fields to change values of hours,minutes and seconds but it doesn't work and I completely have no idea why.

Any suggestion what did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your timer is fixed in the beginning value because are not initializing time value aging in click event of start button, that's why timer is taking its initial value.

Hope this class will clarify this, replace this onCreate method snippet in your Java class here I changed your start click event also replace reset method

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btnStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStart);
    btnStop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStop);
    textViewTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewTime);
    editHours = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editHours);
    editMinutes = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editMinutes);
    editSeconds = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editSeconds);

    btnStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Time = 3600 * Integer.parseInt(editHours.getText().toString())
                    + 60
                    * Integer.parseInt(editMinutes.getText().toString())
                    + Integer.parseInt(editSeconds.getText().toString());

            if (timer != null) {
                timer.cancel();
                timer = null;
            }
            timer = new CounterClass(1000 * Time, 1000);

            timer.start();
        }
    });

    btnStop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            timer.cancel();
            reset();
        }
    });
}
public void reset() {
    if (timer != null) {
        timer.cancel();
    }
    editHours.setText("0");
    editMinutes.setText("0");
    editSeconds.setText("0");
    textViewTime.setText("0");
}
```

Comment: Thx, that was very helpfull but there is additional notes need - definition of timer can't be final.

Comment: Just declare  countdown time as Filed i.e class variable              private CounterClass timer not local variable, if not done then I will post the whole class.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I got your question correctly, by beginning value of time do you mean on click of the stop button the timer goes to the initial value of the time? If that's the case then it is because when you click on the stop button you are calling the reset method.

Comment: Yeah and this value is alway this same. But after i click on stop button every textfields are being cleared, so I can put new values. But it doesn't being read.
Additionaly in xml file there is line in every textedit field:
          android:text="0"
Cause if I don't put it, my program can''t run. I think this is the reason why there is always this same value, but how to repair it?

Comment: Can you try adding the below code inside your button onClickListener:    editHours = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editHours);
editMinutes = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editMinutes);
editSeconds = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editSeconds);

Comment: Also try removing the lines that says android:text="1" from your xml and instead use editHours.setText("1") and so on in your onCreate method.